# How does GraphQl handle conflicting operation names?

Tags: graphql, nosql, graphql-java

Working on a large codebase, I came across 2 exposed graphql mutations with the same name. To my understanding, these should give an error when generating the graphql schema, yet the site is perfectly functional. Both these mutations have the same method arguments as well.

I want to know what are the rules on conflicting operation names in graphql? Are multiple operations allowed to have the same name?

How is the fact that they have the same set of arguments being dealt with? Which method gets actually called? I saw another example pair with same name and different arguments. When i checked the exposed schema the arguments have been combined into one long list and exposed.

A link towards the correct part of documentation would be more than helpful. I cannot seem to find it.

Thanks for the help :)